# Horizontal UIScrollView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

How to create horizontal `UIScrollView` in iOS to look like in image?

[image: with center it is auto select[1]]

```
float width = self.view.frame.size.width/3;
    int x = width;
    float height = scrCategory.frame.size.height;
    for(int i = 0;i<arrCategory.count;i++)
    {
        UIButton *btnCategory = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btnCategory.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, width, height);
        [btnCategory setTag:i+1];
        [btnCategory setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrCategory objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnCategory setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnCategory addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCategoryAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btnCategory setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [scrCategory addSubview:btnCategory];
        x = x + width;
    }
    [scrCategory setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x+width, height)];
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Can u post your code what have u done ?

Comment: Create multiple labels inside ScrollView, and set the width of them.

Comment: @khuong291 i am also done that..

Comment: Have you set the width for scrollview?

Comment: @khuong291 here is my code.

Comment: Tip: Always add the code when you first post the question to avoid down votes.

Comment: What problem are you facing? Not scrolling? Not showing?

Answer (score 0):

Use iCarousel https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel
Or 
Use UICollectionview with pagination.

Set fixed background image (black bar with selection).

Answer (score 0):

```
    int x =10;
    int y = 5;
    int height = 90;
    self.scrlView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<images.count;i++)
        {
            UIButton *intrestBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [intrestBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 80, 80)];
            [self.scrlView addSubview:intrestBtn];

            x = x +95;
            self.scrlView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x+SCREEN_WIDTH,90 );
            [self.scrlView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
        }
```

This is how I used to do it

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use UICollectionView? 
All you need is create custom cell with 1 label. No custom layout, just configure *UICollectionViewFlowLayout*